# Missing sound on Apple Watch after resume from dock

Tags: sprite-kit, apple-watch, watchos-3

I am using the following sounds (all 32K AAC as mentioned in Apple document but I use mono instead of stereo: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideo.html) for my watchOS 3 games.

```
let hitSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("hit.m4a", waitForCompletion:false)
let explosionSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("explosion.m4a", waitForCompletion:false)
let music = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "delta.m4a")
```

I use hitSound and explosionSound for short sound effect, and play music on the background, they works fine until the game is quit and resume from dock.

The music is resume and the sound effects are no longer heard. Is there any problem with using SKAction.playSoundFileNamed to play sound?

Comment: Could you provide more code?  my guess is that explosionSound is no longer in memory

Comment: @Knight0fDragon my guess too. The rest of the codes are just simple play of the sounds, what codes you want to see? How do we avoid the losing of sound in memory after returning from Dock?

Comment: no idea,  for all I know explosionSound is local